# Communication between two nodes in a hyperledger network

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

How does the nodes in a hyperledger network communicate with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of nodes:

Client or submitting-client: a client that submits an actual transaction-invocation to the endorsers, and broadcasts transaction-proposals to the ordering service.

Peer: a node that commits transactions and maintains the state and a copy of the ledger. Besides, peers can have a special endorser role.

Ordering-service-node or orderer: a node running the communication service that implements a delivery guarantee, such as atomic or total order broadcast.

gRPC protocol is used communication between various entities of hyperledger fabric.